# How settings of a browser is imported to other?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, import

Recently I installed Mozilla Firefox in my Windows system. After installation a window appeared asking to import settings from IE. How can a different browser like Firefox import the settings of IE ? What is the advantages of importing settings ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can do it because you gave it Administrator access during the install, and/or it's only collecting user-level information from your account.

So it goes and reads the configuration files of the other browser(s), which are kept in a standard place on all Windows machines.

A prime example of an advantage is not having to re-create all your favorites/bookmarks, and retype saved passwords, etc.

More information on what FF imports from IE can be found [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/import-bookmarks-internet-explorer).

Answer (score 1):

This page specifies a bit of what is imported and how to do it after installation.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/import-bookmarks-internet-explorer

As far as how, Mozilla has a way for data from Internet Explorer, Google Chrome and Safari (Maybe Opera too) to be read and converted into a format that Firefox uses.

This is useful if you want to import Bookmarks from Internet Explorer, as well as your home page (and a couple other things you can see described on that link).